# Determine the tensor of contraint and deformation of a cube under compression

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity, tensor-calculus

We have a cube under compression with dimension l1*l2*l3, is put between 2 rigid plates in the axis 1 (two plates block the deformation of the cube in thí axis), the cube is also put on a rigid plate, and it has a rigid plate above it; 
and also this cube is under the force F from above (axis 3). The material of the cube is isotropic, linear elastic.
The deformation of the cube is ∆l2 and ∆l3 (since the deformation of the axis 1 is block)

The question is: How to write/determine the tensor of constrain and tensor of deformation?
Is this below one is correct?

$\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{\sigma }_{11}} & {{\sigma }_{12}} & {{\sigma }_{13}}  \\
   {{\sigma }_{21}} & {{\sigma }_{22}} & {{\sigma }_{23}}  \\
   {{\sigma }_{31}} & {{\sigma }_{32}} & {{\sigma }_{33}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\left( \begin{matrix}
   {{\sigma }_{11}} & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & {{\sigma }_{33}}  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$

and

$\left( \begin{matrix}
   0 & 0 & 0  \\
   0 & {{\varepsilon }_{22}}={}^{\Delta {{l}_{2}}}\!\!\diagup\!\!{}_{{{l}_{2}}}\; & 0  \\
   0 & 0 & {{\varepsilon }_{33}}=-{}^{\Delta {{l}_{3}}}\!\!\diagup\!\!{}_{{{l}_{3}}}\;  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$

Comment: Could you decrypt the first sentence or provide a picture instead? How many plates are there 2 or 4?

Comment: Thanks for viewing my question, here's the image, excuse me for not being clear earlier :) here's the image:
http://i.imgur.com/KCedn.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer for the strain tensor is correct, but for not  the stress (*on utilise "stress" en anglais, pas "contraint"*). Since you know $\epsilon_{ij}$ you can immediately calculate the stress tensor  from Hooke's law:

$$\sigma_{ij}=2\mu\epsilon_{ij} +\lambda \operatorname{tr}(\epsilon) \delta_{ij}$$

to get
$$\sigma=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \lambda  \left(\frac{\Delta l_2}{l_2}+\frac{\Delta l_3}{l_3}\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{(\lambda +2 \mu ) \Delta l_2}{l_2}+\frac{\lambda  \Delta l_3}{l_3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{\lambda  \Delta l_2}{l_2}+\frac{(\lambda +2 \mu ) \Delta l_3}{l_3}
\end{array}
\right)$$